# How to package up a Python 3 script with modules

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I created a small script that uses a few 3rd-party modules. I'm not sure how to distribute it. I tried Pyinstaller, but that doesn't seem to work. It can't find the modules. When I give the binary to a co-worker, it says it is looking for files in my home directory ( not his ) and dies. I have found that Pyinstaller is not able to find most modules. I am running Python 3 and installed Pyinstaller with pip from Python 2. It did not work trying to use pip from Python 3. When, I give it a path to my modules, it complains that they are python 3 modules. Just looking for some clarification. Ultimately, I'd like to run this on a linux or OS X box where python and my modules probably won't be installed. I just started Python yesterday and have a ton to learn.

Answer (score 0):

you want to build a standalone executable file, or just a distribution package.
If you want standalone executable file try [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) it supports python 3.x
Or if you want a distribution package then look at this documentation http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/